# Code works in console but not in Hackerank

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, palindrome

My code works in console but gives the wrong result in hackerank
Problem: Print count of all substrings that are palindromes from a string

```js
function isPalindrome(str) {

  var len = str.length;
  var mid = Math.floor(len / 2);

  for (var i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  //Had to use this lengthy function because in
  //str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
  //I was getting error that split is not a function
  return true;
}

function scatterPalindrome(str) {
  var result = [],
    c = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < str.length + 1; j++) {
      result.push(str.slice(i, j));
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    let k = result[i];
    if (isPalindrome(k))
      c++;
  }
  return c; // the answer was always 1
}
console.log(scatterPalindrome("abc"));
```

input: "abc"

expected output: 3

actual output:1

Comment: Are you asking for help to complete a HankerRank question as part of a job interview?

Comment: no, i was practising , I just need to know why the same code that worked in console is not working somewhere else( hackerank)

Comment: I cannot understand, how this code would produce a count of `1` on the input of `abc` (or any input with length > 1) as each single character is counted as palindrome

Comment: yes, thats what my question is

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment, so answering here, I will say you should check if they have mentioned there are many test cases, and in each test case you have to do the query then this is reasonable that your output and their output will not match

```
    take no.of testcases input
    while(testcases counter doesn't reach 0 )
           take string input
           call your function for answer for input and print
           decrement testcases counter
```